# Run script on remote server from local machine

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, remote-server

I have a remote script on a machine (B) which works perfectly when I run it from machine (B). I wanted to run the script via ssh from machine (A) using:

```
ssh usersm@${RHOST} './product/2018/requests/inbound/delDup.sh'
```

However, machine (A) complains about the contents of the remote script (2018req*.txt is a variable defined at the beginning of the script):

```
ls: cannot access 2018req*.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: can you show the beginning of your script? And are you sure that those files are present on your remote machine (B)?

Comment: globbing doesn't transmit well through SSH.  I suggest that you find the synonymous way to do what you need to do with `find` instead.

Answer (score 2):

From the information provided, it's hard to do more than guess. So here's a guess: when you run the script directly on machine B, do you run it from your home directory with `./product/2018/requests/inbound/delDup.sh`, or do you `cd` into the product/2018/requests/inbound directory and run it with `./delDup.sh`? If so, using `2018req*.txt` will look in different places; basically, it looks in the directory that you were in when you ran the script. If you `cd`ed to the inbound directory locally, it'll look there, but running it remotely doesn't change to that directory, so `2018req*.txt` will look for files in the home directory.

If that's the problem, I'd rewrite the script to `cd` to the appropriate directory, either by hard-coding the absolute path directly in the script, or by detecting what directory the script's in (see ["https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/getting-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/getting-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within) and [BashFAQ #28: "How do I determine the location of my script? I want to read some config files from the same place"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028)).

BTW, anytime you use `cd` in a script, you should test the exit status of the `cd` command to make sure it succeeded, because if it didn't the rest of the script will execute in the wrong place and may do unexpected and unpleasant things. You can use `||` to run an error handler if it fails, like this:

```
cd somedir || {
    echo "Cannot cd to somedir" >&2
    exit 1
}
```

If that's not the problem, please supply more info about the script and the situation it's running in (i.e. location of files). The best thing to do would be to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Basically, make a copy of the script, remove everything that isn't relevant to the problem, make sure it still exhibits the problem (otherwise you removed something that *was* relevant), and add that (and file locations) to the question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all when you use SSH, instead of directly sending the output (`stdout` and `stderr`) to the monitor, the remote machine/`ssh` server sends the data back to the machine from which you started the `ssh` connection. The `ssh` client running in your local machine will just display it (except if you redirect it of course).

Now, from the information you have provided, it looks like the files are not present on server (B) or not accessible (last but not least, are you sure your `ls` target the proper directory? ) you could display the current directory in your script before running the `ls` command for debugging purpose.